# PIL to Qimage conversion: QImage constructor does not free memory

Tags: python-imaging-library, qimage

I am developping a Qt application **loading** pictures with **PIL**, modifying colors and alpha channels, then **converting them as QImage**.

Here is the problematic piece of code:  normal **repeated usage of the ImageQt** function:

```py
    # memory is filled  around 7 mB/s
    if name == 'main':
        while True:
            im = Image.open('einstein.png') #small picture
            imQt = QtGui.QImage(ImageQt.ImageQt(im)) # convert to PySide.QtGui.QImage
            imQt.save('outtest.png')# -> rendered picture is correct
            #del(imQt) and del(im) does not change anything
            time.sleep(0.02)
```

The problem here is the **crazy memory filling**, when the picture is supposed to be erased by the garbage collector. I checked with gc.collect(), but it did not change anything.

This example shows what happends with the **imageQt** function, but in fact, I noticed this is a problem caused by QImage: **if you repeatedly use the QImage constructor with data, the memory used by python process increases**:

```py
    im= Image.load('mypic.png').convert('RGBA')
    data = im.toString('raw','RGBA')
    qIm = QtGui.QImage(data,im.size[0],im.size[1],QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    qIm.save('myConvertedPic.png')# -> picture is perfect
```

If you put this code in a loop, memory will increase, as 1st example. From there i am a bit lost because this is a PySide problem...

I tried to use a workaround, but it does not work either:

```py
    #Workaround, but not working ....

    if name == 'main':
        while True:
            im = Image.open('einstein.png') #small picture
            imRGBA = im.convert('RGBA') # convert to RGBA
            imRGBA.save('convtest.png') # ->picture is looks perfect
            imBytes = imRGBA.tostring('raw','RGBA')
            #print("size %d %d" % (imRGBA.size[0],imRGBA.size[1]))
            qImage = QtGui.QImage(imRGBA.size[0],imRGBA.size[1],QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32) # create new empty picture
            qImage.fill(QtCore.Qt.blue) # fill with blue, otherwise it catches pieces of the picture still in memory
            loaded = qImage.loadFromData(imBytes,'RGBA') # load from raw data
            print("success %d" % loaded)# -> returns 0
            qImage.save('outtest.png')# -> rendered picture is blue
            time.sleep(0.02)
```

I am really stuck here, if you could help **find a solution with this workaround** ? Because I'm really stuck here!
Also I would like to **discuss the QImage problem**. Is there any reliable way to free this memory ? Could the fact I am using python3.2(32bits) be a problem in this case ? Am I the only one in this case ?

The imports I am using in case of:

```py
    import time
    import sys
    import PySide
    sys.modules['PyQt4'] = PySide # this little hack allows to solve naming problem when using PIL with Pyside (instead of PyQt4)
    from PIL import Image, ImageQt
    from PySide import QtCore,QtGui
```

Answer (score 0):

After further unsuccessful searching, I noticed, that the PIL function **image.tostring()** associated with a **QImage constructor** caused this problem

```
    im = Image.open('einstein.png').convert('RGBA')
    data = im.tostring('raw','RGBA') # the tostring() function is out of the loop
    while True:
        imQt = QtGui.QImage(data,im.size[0],im.size[1],QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        #imQt.save("testpic.png") #image is valid
        time.sleep(0.01)
        #no memory problem !
```

I think I am really close to find what is wrong, but I cannot point it out.
It definitely has something to do with the `data` variable being held in memory.

Comment: I have been bumping into a related problem.  I believe that PIL does not account for its "data" pointer in images correctly.  In my case I have a problem where the associated memory gets "free" called multiple times, and the crash/stack dump correlated with that.

Comment: `img.tostring("raw", "RGBA", 0, -1))` is how daeview form pycollada does that